# prevent duplicate results when joining the same query postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to join the same query in postgresql, but I only need one row per couple of columns; i.e. I don't want a row containing column1 -- column2, as well as a row containing column2 -- column1.

Example:

```
WITH q AS

(...)

SELECT q1.title AS title1, q2.title AS title2 
FROM 
    q AS q1 
    INNER JOIN 
    q AS q2 USING(id) 
WHERE q1.title != q2.title
```

EDIT: Assuming multiple titles can be recognised by the same id (kind of a bad choice of name)

So q is a predefined query, which has two columns, being "title" and "id". Combining them this way logically gives me these results:

```
title1 -- title2

x1 -- y1

y1 -- x1

...

xn -- yn

yn -- xn
```

etc. But I only need the `xi -- yi` sets `(0 < i <= n)`.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Why you can't use `Group By`?

Comment: because the ID can appear multiple times still in the result. so, i can have

x -- y -- id=b |
x -- z -- id=b |
y -- z -- id=b
and I'd need all these results. unless i'm wrong about what group by does, of course

Comment: either way i don't think group by would work considering i need all these pairs specifically.

Comment: i mean that group by can be for more columns. Something like: `Group By title1, title2`.

Comment: It wouldn't work since x, y and y, x would be different groups, so both would be there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `!=` for `<`

```
WHERE q1.title < q2.title
```

Comment: Seems to work. Is it because comparators look at positions in the list here? I didn't know that. Thanks!